# Display x tick values for all bins in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame which has an Earning column and I'm trying to display a histogram using ggplot. I need to start the histogram at 40000 (minimum value is 40003) and end the histogram at 400000 with bins of width = 20000.
Below is the code I wrote and it displays the histogram. But I want to display the x tick values as well for all bins. For e.g., in the graph the bins should have x-axis value as 40000, 60000, 80000 and so on. Below is my code

```
ggplot(boston, aes(x=Earnings)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks=seq(40000,400000,by=20000),binwidth = 20000, fill="#69b3a2", color="#e9ecef", alpha=1)
```

[image]

Help from the community is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try with `scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(40000,400000,by=20000))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include bin labels, use this:

```
ggplot(boston, aes(x=Earnings)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 20000, fill="#69b3a2", color="#e9ecef") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="Earnings (thousands)",limits=c(40000, 400000),
                     breaks=seq(40000,400000,by=20000),
                     labels=number_format(accuracy=1, scale=1/1000)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

The label scaling is optional. You also can change the text angle.